# Est-ce que le choix du temps l'emporte sur le choix du mode?

Tags: temps-grammatical, mode-grammatical

Je vois très souvent ce genre de phrase: « Ça a bien marché, je ne pensais pas que ça pouvait arriver », mais il me semblait qu'il faille (ou fallait?) utiliser le subjonctif et non l'imparfait de l'indicatif.

Merci d'avance

Comment: *il me semblait qu'il fallait* semble plus naturel dans ce cas.

Answer (score 3):

L'imparfait du subjonctif est un temps qui, même à l'écrit et hors registre soutenu (voire très soutenu), a tendance à ne plus être utilisé. Son utilisation est correcte mais n'est plus en phase avec l'usage dans la plupart des cas.

Hormis cette exception, utiliser le mauvais mode est une faute, bien que certaines utilisations erronées soient courantes, par exemple l'utilisation du présent de l'indicatif au lieu du présent du subjonctif comme dans la phrase:
*Il faut que j'**aie** au moins 10 à mon prochain partiel.* où *j'aie* et *j'ai* sont homophones.

Comment: Alors, l’utilisation de l’imparfait de l’indicatif après une autre dans une phrase où il y faut un temps du subjonctif (comme l'indique « ne pas penser que », « falloir que ») que ce soit le présent ou le passé, et non l'imparfait comme vous l'avez dit, est-elle toujours une faute même si elle soit courante?

Comment: D'ordinaire, le présent du subjonctif est utilisé à la place de l'imparfait du subjonctif. Mais dans certains cas, le présent du subjonctif peut sonner trop soutenu pour le contexte, ou avoir une connotation trop générale (bien que ce soit une simple nuance). Dans les exemples de la réponse de jlliagre, *que ça/cela puisse arriver* est plutôt soutenu et généralise (que ça puisse arriver en général) alors que *que ça/cela pouvait arriver* est moins soutenu et limite l'affirmation à une période antérieure au moment où c'est effectivement arrivé.

Answer (score 2):

En complément de la réponse de Sacha, il ne faut pas négliger la cohérence à laquelle on s'attend au sein d'une même phrase.

Le pronom ***ça*** est du registre courant ou relâché, il n'est donc pas vraiment compatible avec l'imparfait du subjonctif ***pût*** qui est d'un registre très soutenu.

✓ Je ne pensais pas que ça pouvait arriver (courant, y compris à l'écrit aujourd'hui)
✓ Je ne pensais pas que cela pouvait arriver (soutenu, rare à l'oral)
✓ Je ne pensais pas que ça puisse arriver (hybride)
✓ Je ne pensais pas que cela puisse arriver (soutenu)
✘ Je ne pensais pas que ça pût arriver (registres trop différents, introuvable)
✓ Je ne pensais pas que cela pût arriver (très soutenu, littéraire mais la norme à l'écrit jusqu'au milieu du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle)

Comment: *Je ne pensais pas que cela pourrait arriver (un jour)* est une autre possibilité correcte, non ?

Comment: @XouDo Oui, bien sûr. C'est aussi possible, le conditionnel est clairement un futur du passé dans ce cas.